# Обновить информацию в базе данных c#

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть база данных gallery, в которой 7 связанных таблиц. Необходимо после изменения данных в dataGrivView1 после нажатия на кнопку значения менялись в базе данных. После нажатия на кнопку, ничего не происходит. Код:

```
        private void обновитьТаблицуToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string command = "SELECT picture_name AS 'Название картины', full_name AS 'Художник',genre_name AS 'Жанр',style_name AS 'Стиль',date_crt AS 'Дата создания' FROM `picture`,`painter`,`genre`,`style` WHERE painter.id_painter = picture.id_painter AND genre.id_genre = picture.id_genre AND style.id_style = painter.id_style";
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command, connection);
        MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        adapter.Update((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не работаю с адаптерами но вроде должно быть так

```
    private void обновитьТаблицуToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(connection);
    adapter.Update((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
}
```

а у вас сейчас

1. string command = "SELECT это для запроса для обновления команда **UPDATE  set value**
2. создаете даблицу **DataTable dt = new DataTable();**
3. заполняете таблицу данными с базы данных **adapter.Fill(dt);**
4. выводите данные в **dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;**
5. a после того как данные скачались вы их хотите обновить **adapter.Update((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);**

обновлять нечего т.к данные актуальные.

Comment: Не работает, ибо при иниализации адаптера необходимо указывать команду, а не тольок connection=(

Comment: укажите тогда старую команду тогда старую команду , если не сработает то придется писать UPDATE set

Comment: Не помогло) Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource" к типу "System.Data.DataTable".

Comment: Вот ссылка по вашему адаптеру https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: вам придется писать Update Set где надо указать какие поля обновлять

Comment: Точно не вариант. Для составления подобного запроса необходимо знать, какие поля были изменены...

Comment: Вот есчо один пример https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/61b832/sqldataadapter-update-method/ более простой но влюбом случаи придется писать Update Set можете циклом пройтись по dagridview и обновить все и вам не надо знать что изменилось